# Side-by-side elements without using tables

Tags: html, css

I've noticed that StackOverflow resorted to using a table-based layout for the comments area beneath posts:

[image]

Notice how the text all stays to the right of the button area, regardless of how many lines of text there are. I am trying to accomplish the same effect using a table-less layout, and failing miserably. Is there any good way to do achieve this without tables?

Comment: bah! too many answers. Here's my take on it : http://jsfiddle.net/RjeL9/1/

Comment: @JohnP: That's an interesting approach. I don't much like having to define the elements in the opposite order from how I expect them to appear. Nor do I like having to throw an empty div there. It doesn't feel very semantically correct to me.

Comment: I'm actually terrible in frontend stuff ^_^

Comment: I viewed the site source for the exact same reason just a few weeks ago. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good start:

```
<div class="comment-row">
    <ul class="icon-set">
        <li class="icon-1"><a href="">icon</a></li>
        <li class="icon-2"><a href="">icon</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="comment">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.comment-row { position relative; }
.icon-set { position: absolute; }
.icon-set a {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 16px;
}
.comment { margin-left: 30px; }
```

Live Sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/HPbFJ/

Answer (score 1):

```
.sidebyside { float: left}
<div class="sidebyside">
    <input type="button" value="VoteUp" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Flag" />
</div>
<div class="sidebyside">Text</div>
```

Isn't it just as simple as this?

EDIT

Your example (fixed):

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="float: left;">Left Content</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 100px;">Right Content Right ContentRight Content Right Content Right Content Right Content Right Content Right Content Right Content Right Content Right Content Right Content Right Content Right Content Right Content Right Content Right Content Right Content Right Content Right Content Right Content  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. See http://jsfiddle.net/UxhLr/4 for an example of the problem.

Comment: Fair enough, since StackOverflow specifies a width. +1. In my particular case, gutierrezalex's answer will work better.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution: http://jsfiddle.net/7JukV/

Just for the sake of alternatives... :)

Comment: Can you get the buttons to appear in the right place if there is more than one "comment?" http://jsfiddle.net/7JukV/1/